# Python strip pattern match from line

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to strip the timestamp via pattern match on a log file using this code

```
        searchfile = open(file, "r")
        pattern1 = ("STRING1", "STRING2")
        pattern2 = ("STRING1", "STRING3")
        for line in searchfile:
            if all(s in line for s in pattern1):
                time1 = line.strip().split()
                print("Start: " + time1[3])
            if all(s in line for s in pattern2):
                time2 = line.strip().split()
                print("End: " + time2[3])
```

However when i run it, the "End" print is appearing twice with the 1st "End" inheriting the value, of the "Start"

Output below;

```
Start: 00:00:01:543
End: 00:00:01:543
End: 00:00:01:841
Start: 00:00:05:645
End: 00:00:05:645
End: 00:00:05:903
Start: 00:00:12:408
End: 00:00:12:408
End: 00:00:12:640
Start: 00:00:14:648
End: 00:00:14:648
End: 00:00:14:871
Start: 00:00:22:677
End: 00:00:22:677
End: 00:00:22:916
```

I cant have another for loop for the "End" time because it would not result to a sequential "Start-End" output. I tried to assign a different variable name for the "End" time but still the results are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Just found that the problem is on the pattern2 string filters. The old criteria strings resulted into two result set which also include the result set of pattern1. Need to include another criteria string on pattern 2 and it works now.

```
Start: 00:00:01:543
End: 00:00:01:841
Start: 00:00:05:645
End: 00:00:05:903
Start: 00:00:12:408
End: 00:00:12:640
Start: 00:00:14:648
End: 00:00:14:871
Start: 00:00:22:677
End: 00:00:22:916
Start: 00:00:27:419
End: 00:00:27:649
Start: 00:00:31:633
End: 00:00:31:858
Start: 00:00:35:605
End: 00:00:35:857
Start: 00:00:40:314
End: 00:00:40:597
Start: 00:00:41:875
End: 00:00:42:110
```